# How to change localization settings in an AngularJs application?

Tags: angularjs, localization

I'm trying to adapt the dates in my application depending on the localization.

I tried to change the `$locale.id = 'fr-fr'`, but it doesn't update the object so texts stays in english (`en-us` is the default `$locale.id`).

Then I tried to force a language by including this in my `index.html`:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/Angular/i18n/angular-locale_fr.js"></script>
```

But on my controllers, I still get the `en-us` on the  `$locale.id` and all the english translations:

```
$locale = Object {DATETIME_FORMATS: Object, NUMBER_FORMATS: Object, id: "en-us"}
```

How can I control/change the `$locale` service language ?

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, `$locale.id` is a read-only property, you cannot set the locale this way.
You can have a look at the [angular-dynamic-locale](https://github.com/lgalfaso/angular-dynamic-locale) where locale can be set dynamically:

```
tmhDynamicLocale.set('it');
```

The module itself is well documented on its github page.

The [angular-dynamic-locale] is needed only if you want to switch your locale on the fly, in most cases you just want to set a single locale for your application.

For that, you can read the [*i18n guide* from the angular docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/i18n) at the section *Providing locale rules to Angular* where the two ways to specify the locale for your angular application are described:

1. Pre-bundled rule sets
2. Including a locale script in index.html